# Efeito zoom com CSS

Tags: css, css3, css-hover, css-transições, css-animations

Tenho uma div com uma imagem na qual apliquei um efeito zoom e uma leve rotação!
porém essa imagem deve fazer o zoom e a rotação dentro dos limites da DIV sem transbordar e sim ocultar as partes que excedam o tamanho da div.

imagem explicando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```css
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: 0;
 }
 body {
     font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
 }
    ul, ol, li {
        list-style: none;
    }
 
 .imagem {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 14%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-grid;
  position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
 .imagem img {
  width: 100%;
        max-width:260px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5%;
 }
 .imagem img {
    width:100%;
  -webkit-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
   -moz-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
    -ms-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
     -o-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
     transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
 }
 .imagem:hover > img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg) ;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg) ;
  -o-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg) ;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg) ;
  transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg);
 }
```

```html
<div class="imagem">
 <img alt="folder" src="https://i.imgur.com/7s6gp01.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar `overflow: hidden;` no seu elemento?

Comment: Ao invés do `scale`, tentou com a propriedade `zoom`? Não é tão recomendada, mas pode funcionar diferente do `scale` na questão de não sair para fora dos limites da div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível resolver isso usando `padding` e um *pseudo-elemento* `::after`. Vc tem que tirar a cor de fundo da `div` imagem e usar o *pseudo-elemento* como cor de `backgroud`. Depois faz um ajuste de `padding` para o `overflow:hidden` não cortar a imagem antes da hora.

Veja como ficou o resultado. *(deixei os comentário no código)*

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
ul, ol, li {
    list-style: none;
}

.imagem {
    width: 14%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-grid;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 6px 0px 6px 6px; /* ajuste de padding para não cortar a imagem */
    overflow: hidden; /* esconde a imagem no :hover */
}

 /* elemento com a cor de fundo */
.imagem::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -6px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    z-index: -1;
}
.imagem img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width:265px;

    -webkit-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
        -moz-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
            -ms-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
            -o-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
                transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
}
.imagem:hover > img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg) ;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg) ;
    -o-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg) ;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg) ;
    transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="imagem">
    <img alt="folder" src="https://i.imgur.com/7s6gp01.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: resolveu, porém como eu faria o mesmo com outra estrutura no html?

Comment: @Arthur74 cara editei completamente a pergunta. Ontem eu estava na casa da minha noivo no notebooke da minha sogra e não deu para fazer melhor hahah. Mas fiquei matutando nisso e consegui em um resultado muito melhor sem precisar mexer no html, apenas ajustei o padding e usei um pseudo elemento ::after. Olha ai que ficou praticamente idêntico a imagem!

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi assim:

```css
 * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: 0;
 }
 body {
     font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
 }
    ul, ol, li {
        list-style: none;
    }
 
 .imagem {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 14%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-grid;
  position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
 }
 .imagem img {
  width: 100%;
        max-width:255px;
 
  -webkit-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
   -moz-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
    -ms-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
     -o-transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
     transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(.190, 1.000, .220, 1.000);
 }
 .imagem:hover > img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg) ;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg) ;
  -o-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg) ;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg) ;
  transform: scale(1.5) rotate(-5deg);
 }
```

```html
<div class="imagem">
  <img alt="folder" src="https://i.imgur.com/7s6gp01.jpg"/>
 </div>
```